# Differential matrix word problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

A vector $y=[R(t) F(t)]^{T}$ describes the populations of some rabbits $R(t)$ and foxes $F(t)$. The populations obey the system of differential equations given by $y′  =  Ay$ where

$A = \begin{bmatrix}-10&70\\-3&19\end{bmatrix}$

The rabbit population begins at 30000. If we want the rabbit population to grow as a simple exponential of the form $R(t)  =  R_0e^{4t}$  with no other terms, how many foxes are needed at time $t = 0$?

My attempt:

$\lambda = 4, \begin{bmatrix}14&-70\\3&-15\end{bmatrix}$

$\lambda = 5, \begin{bmatrix}15&-70\\3&-14\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}3&-14\\-3&15\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}-10&70\\-3&19\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}5&14/3\\1&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&5\end{bmatrix}$

so i get
$\begin{bmatrix}e^{5t}\\e^{4t}\end{bmatrix}$

then, $\begin{bmatrix}5&14/3\\1&1\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}e^{5t}\\e^{4t}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}(15e^{5t}+14e^{4x})/3\\e^{5t}+14e^{4x}\end{bmatrix}$

Now I have no idea what or how I should approach this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your matrix $A$ represent?  What equations determine the populations of rabbits and foxes at time $t$?

Comment: Matrix $A$ is the system of equations that represents how the rabbit population effects the fox population and vice versa

Comment: @Forextrader: Does $x$ represent rabbits and $y$ foxes? Were initial conditions given? Can you write the problem exactly as given?

Comment: I edited the question at the top.

Comment: That's better.  Hint: the general solution is of the form $ c_1 v_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 v_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$ where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $v_1$ and $v_2$ corresponding eigenvectors.  But here you want only one of the coefficients $c_i$ to be nonzero.

Comment: Ok, so I would now have $c_1 \begin{bmatrix}5\\1\end{bmatrix}e^{4t}$ and $ c_2 \begin{bmatrix}14/3\\1\end{bmatrix}e^{5t}$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I really don't understand.

Comment: Right, so you just want the $c_1 \left[\matrix{5\cr 1\cr}\right] e^{4t}$.  And then if $5 c_1 = 30000$, what is ...?

Comment: 30000/5 = 6000?

Comment: I dont know enough about this topic to even give you an informed answer. We went over differentials in class for all of 30 minutes.